# How to index a list based on user input, and print the result

Tags: python, list, input, indexing, printing

Here is what i am trying to do.. I want the user to pick a number, and then print word from my list that the number indexes. 
This is what i have so far

```
mylist = ["john","jack","jen","judy","jill"]
mylist
add = input("please state a name")
mylist.append(add)
print (mylist)
add = input("please state a number")
```

Comment: When you're asking a question about code, the very first tag you should add is the one for the language you're using.

Comment: If this is a python question, add the `python` tag.

Comment: To get the element of a list at position n, you would say "mylist[n]". Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Um, i dont believe so. Here is what im asked to do " Ask a user to input a number. Print the name that has that number as index"

Comment: You would improve the problem's explanation to understand it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
index = input("please state a number")
index = int(index)
name = mylist[index]
print(name)
```